# Using JUnit to run testcases which involve dialog boxes which take in user input

Tags: java, swing, junit

I am building an application which helps a user navigate a website by giving step by step instructions.
The instructions are given in the form of dialog boxes. I am using Java Swing to create the GUI dialog boxes.

This is the main class which starts the webdriver.

```
public class initialDriver{

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        testCases.simpleGoogle();
        testCases.wiki();


}

}
```

Control passes to this class. This consists of the individual test cases. Each testcase sends arguements for the GUI.

```
public class testCases{


    public static void simpleGoogle() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        initialDriver.driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        initialDriver.driver.get("https://www.google.com"); 

        String message = "Enter search term,Click search button,Check the results";

        new StepMessage("GoogleSearch",message);

    }


    public static void wiki() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        initialDriver.driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        initialDriver.driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org"); 

        String message = "Enter 'Solar Energy',Click search,Check the page";

        new StepMessage("WikipediaSearch",message);     

    }

}
```

This is the GUI class. On clicking 'OK', it opens another GUI frame which takes in user input for 'Testcase - Pass or Fail'.

```
public class StepMessage extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static javax.swing.JTextArea msgArea;

        public String message;
        public String nameoftheTest;

    public static javax.swing.JButton btnOk;



    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public StepMessage(String Testname,String message) {

        nameoftheTest = Testname;

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 226);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        msgArea = new JTextArea();
        msgArea.setBounds(12, 13, 397, 68);
        contentPane.add(msgArea);
        msgArea.setEditable(false);
        StepMessage.msgArea.setText(message);


        btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.setBounds(175, 135, 97, 30);
        contentPane.add(btnOk);
        btnOk.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                OkBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });



    }



    public void OkBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        this.dispose();
        PassFail frame2 = new PassFail(nameoftheTest);
        frame2.setTitle("Test Pass or Fail");
        frame2.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I want to run multiple such tests using JUnit. Each test must navigate to website, open the GUI and wait for user input. Then the control should pass back to the testCases class and execute the next test.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (or if not available, Guava's [SettableFuture)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html). Write the test like:

```
@Test
public void testGoogle() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    testCases.simpleGoogle(future);
    future.get();
}
```

and pass the future through the UI so it's available in the event handlers. Then call either `future.complete(null)` or `future.completeExceptionally(new AssertionError("Failed"))` depending on whether the test has passed or failed.